# cat file that contains escaped characters to netcat

Tags: shell, escaping, cat, netcat

I'm trying to test a webserver with some HTTP request written in a file.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n
```

Right now I'm feeding that file to `netcat` like this:

```
cat files | nc localhost 80
```

However, the `\r\n` in the files are transfered directly to webserver(resulting in 4 chars, i.e. '\','r','\','n'). How can I feed that file so that chars are escaped correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\r\n` are the codes used in a printf statement to generate CarridgeReturn/NewLine line endings used by DOS/Windows.

As you are using cat, you are using some variant of unix which only uses `\n` as line end.
BUT you don't have to have that char appear in the file. Just try removing those values (leaving a real Newline at the end of the line).

Example test file now =

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
  blah-blah

GET / HTTP/1.1
  blah2
```

OR if you really must interpret the `\r\n` values embedded in the file, you can interpret the file with the printf utiltity, i.e.

```
$ cat printf_inputtest.txt
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n
$ printf "$( < printf_inputtest.txt )"
GET / HTTP/1.1


GET / HTTP/1.1

$
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Usavich : please see my final edits. I believe I have solved your problem exactly as requested. Good luck.